# How do I disable all sounds?

Tags: sound

In windows there is an option call no sounds.

Is there anything like that in unity / ubuntu 11.10?

I don't ever never want a system kind of sound.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three simple steps:

To **disable system sounds** check `Sound Settings`:

[image: open sound settings]

Mute `Alert Volume`:

[image: sound settings]

To **mute the `Login Sound`** open `Startup Applications`:

[image: startup apps open]

Disable `GNOME Login Sound`:

[image: disable login sound]

To **disable the alert on the login screen** (lightdm) you have to mute it once - it is muted automatically next time you start your system:

[image: mute login sound]

Done.

Comment: So this means there is only 1 system sound, is that correct? Cause it said, alert sound. I got the feeling that all possible sounds wasn't included in the dialog.

Comment: I muted it on my system and I'm not annoyed by any system sound.

Comment: How can I access these settings when I'm using LXDE? Any command line? Some programs make annoying bubble pop sounds upon every dialog box popup, which drives me nuts, and no way to turn off because every tutorial deals with Ubuntu disregarding other flavors altogether... sigh...

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Dash, type "Sound". The sound menu opens. There you can mute all system sounds.

Comment: It only shows the "sound recorder". No sound options at all. (Dash sucks imho)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to install `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` from the Terminal) and head over to org > gnome > desktop > sound and uncheck 'event-sounds'.